# Обновление значения словаря с помощью аргументов (*args)

Tags: python-3.x, словари

Как можно обновить значение словаря, используя `*args`?

К примеру, чтобы получить их из словаря таким же методом, можно сделать так:

```py
import functools, operator


def get(obj, *args):
    return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, args, obj)

obj = {"main": {"key": "value"}, "section": {"key": "value"}}
ret = get(obj, "main", "key")

print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def set_from_args(obj, *args):
    for k in args[:-2]:
        obj = obj[k]
    obj[args[-2]] = args[-1]

obj = {"main": {"key": "value"}, "section": {"key": "value"}}
set_from_args(obj, "main", "key", 123)

print(obj)  # {'main': {'key': 123}, 'section': {'key': 'value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import functools, operator

obj = {"main": {"key": "value1"}, "section": {"key": "value2"}}

def _get(obj, *args, **kargs):
    if kargs:
        obj[args[0]] = kargs
    return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, args, obj)

print(obj)

ret = _get(obj, "main", "key")
print(ret)

ret = _get(obj, "main", "key", key="12345")
print(ret)

ret = _get(obj, "section", "key", key="Hello world")
print(ret)

print(obj)
```

---

Output

```
{'main': {'key': 'value1'}, 'section': {'key': 'value2'}}
value1
12345
Hello world
{'main': {'key': '12345'}, 'section': {'key': 'Hello world'}}
```